# Fluorescence spectrocopy, sensitivity

Tags: analytical-chemistry

lets say we increased the excitation wavelength higher than it should be, what effect would this have on the sensitivity on our analysis, or changing the emission wavelength to a higher value than it would be.
My guess is that the higher wavelength leads to a lower frequency and so lowers the sensitivity but I have no idea what changing the emission wavelength would do?

Comment: How would you change the emission wavelength?

Comment: sorry I mean if we were to raise the wavelength of the florescence spec used to excite the molecules.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha - You could also choose to monitor the emission in a single wavelength experiment at wavelengths $\ne \ \lambda_{max}^{em}$. You may want to do this, for example, to avoid matrix effects.

Comment: @BenNorris Absolutely true! Excitation spectra measured at different wavelength plus repeated experiments after dilution aren't the worst idea. The world is full of dimers ;)